# How can I get quickfix to open results in the previously focused window?

Tags: windows, vim

I wrote the following command to search Vim's help files:

```
command! -n=1 -complete=help SearchHelp \
    help | execute "grep! -i <args> $VIMRUNTIME/doc/ -r" | botright copen
```

Now, for example, when I have forgotten the key to increment the number under the cursor, I can do:

```
:SearchHelp increment
```

to search through the help files.  (The answer turned out to be `<Ctrl-A>`.)

The problem is ... I have a few windows open, and I want quickfix to leave them alone.  When I hit `<Enter>` in the quickfix list, I want it to **open the result in that help window** which I split open at the beginning of the command.

But it doesn't do this.  It seems to prefer to always open the result in the bottom-most of all my editing windows, regardless of which window I was focused on, and with complete disinterest for the help window I opened.  Obviously this moves away from whatever file I happened to be editing in that window (yes I have `:set hidden`), requiring an arbitrary number of `<Ctrl-O>` keys to get back to the file when I have finished browsing the help files.

So how can I get quickfix to open in the previously focused window (ideally that help window that was split open)?

(Incidentally, I sometimes use a [patched version](https://joeytwiddle@github.com/joeytwiddle/grep.vim) of Yegappan Lakshmanan's old `grep.vim` plugin, and somehow this *does* open `:cope` results in the window that had focus before I ran `:Grep`.  I am not sure what's different in the two situations.)

Comment: You might enjoy: `:helpgrep`. See `:h :helpg` for more.

Comment: Hehe thanks.  I do enjoy that, very much!  It fulfils both my requirements (searching the help files, opening in a split help window).  :)

Comment: I opened the same issue for fugitive.vim:
[first and consequences quickfix window results are opening in different windows](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/issues/1229)

Answer (score 1):

The behavior (among others like `:sbuffer`) is controlled by the `'switchbuf'` option. With a value of `useopen`, you can make it re-use a window if it already displays that help page. If you need more control than what is offered by that option, you do need to use a custom command / mapping.

Comment: Thanks, `useopen` does work if I had that particular help txt file open, but if not it still chooses the bottom window.  I am curious what the quickfix's strategy is here, and why it acts differently after the `:Grep` plugin.

Answer (score 0):

So far what I have come up with is to replace that `help` command with:

```
99wincmd j | wincmd s
```

This splits whatever window happens to be at the bottom of the screen, so that when the quickfix clobbers the bottom one, I still have a window that keeps the file visible.

This solution is workable, but not quite as neat as my preferred result, which is to open results in the help window which was split just above the window I was focused on when I ran the command.